# Publicar app ionic browser

Tags: ionic, ionic2

Foi desenvolvido um app em ionic 2 aqui na empresa que eu trabalho, porém, um dos clientes que está utilizando, gostaria de utilizar ele no desktop (via browser).

Como e quais arquivos preciso utilizar para publicar esse app na internet?

Comment: Olá, tive o mesmo problema com ionic 1, consegui publicar e vou tentar lhe ajudar... Na estrutura do projeto existe uma pasta equivalente a www do ionic 1?

Comment: @GabrielSouza, sim, tenho essa pasta....

Comment: vou responder me baseando em ionic1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso não estiver usando nenhum plug-in Cordova não existe nenhum problema(pode usar o iis para publicar como um site normal), basta mover o conteúdo da pasta www(Pasta do ionic 1 use a equivalente para o ionic 2)para o seu servidor.

Observações:
O navegador deve estar atualizado.
O ionic não foi destinado a este uso.
Resposta baseada em ionic1. 
Espero que de certo, se tiver duvidas pode solicitar meu email!!

Comment: Eu tenho um servidor nGinx, funcionou perfeitamente :D Obrigado @gabriel.souza